# PayPal purchase link deprecated?

Tags: url, paypal

For years I have used a link to Paypal to let users purchase from our site:

```
https://www.paypal.com/xclick/business=[OURMAILADDRESS]&item_name=[ProductName]&amount=26%2e80&shipping=0%2e00&no_shipping=0&no_note=1&tax=0&currency_code=EUR&lc=it&bn=PP%2dBuyNowBF&charset=UTF%2d8'
```

The link stopped working about 2 weeks ago.
I cannot find any info on the net about it being deprecated.
Can anyone shine some light on this topic?

Comment: That's a different question.  I've never seen someone use the url to send data successfully tp paypal rather than letting a Form action create the url and send the data that way.

Comment: That format is described in their integration guide (Website Payments
Standard Checkout Integration Guide) from 2006. Here is a snippet: http://pastebin.com/iwy7DCTR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like paypal has removed support for the paypal.com/xclick links that they previously recommended using (in the Website Payments Standard Checkout Integration Guide pdf from 2006).

Change your link to:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=...
```

For subscriptions, use:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick-subscriptions&business=...
```

Comment: Can you provide how you know paypal removed this and how you know the changed link?  What's your source?

Comment: There is no source. However the link stopped working, and it works if you change it to above. The above format is what is given in paypal's documentation (although it says you have to use method post, that doesn't appear to be the case).

Comment: Also, the old link formats appear in paypal's old API documents (Website Payments Standard Checkout Integration Guide from 2006), but do not appear in their current docs.

Comment: so your source is given in paypal documentation.  I'm suggesting that you add that particular documentation to your answer to make both more complete and more useful for someone who wants to use the pp source. Per: "The above format is what is given in paypal's documentation."

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is not showing a 404 not found error.  It goes to paypal's splash screen page.  From there a user can sign in.  The url is redirected towards https://www.paypal.com/home.  Looks like you're had a function there that isn't working any longer.  I haven't seen that before, but do have a possible solution.

If you want to provide users a way to buy with paypal on your site, a common (and not hard) method is in the html with a paypal code such as code you've created on paypal's website (under "settings" you can create a button and paste the code into your website) or by hand creating an html Form with Input fields yourself.

You're sending the data that would be in the Input fields that would show up in the Form $_GET action to paypal in the url.  Paypal doesn't talk about handling data that way.  Maybe whatever was allowing that to work unofficially,no longer does.

There's a lots of examples of how to create a paypal button html code on SO.  I can post some if you'd like.  This site tells the input fields that your url data can be created with: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

Here's an example:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >

  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"> <!-- I'm using cart, you want to stick the buy now option value in here. -->

 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="yoru business signon email">

 <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="EUR">

 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Whats bought">


   <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">

   <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

   <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">

   <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">

   <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">

   <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">

   <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">

  <input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://www.yours.com/OnlinePayButtons.php">


   <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">

   <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_SM.gif:NonHosted">

  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit">
          <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height=".8"> 

  </form>
```

You have to pick out of the link to html variables, what inputs you need in the form.  This gives a structure and idea of what it looks like.